# getTriangleList() OpenCV C++ giving weird results

Tags: c++, opencv

How does the getTriangleList() in OpenCV for C++ work? Particularly, we get many some additional points as the triangle points as well, where do these points pop up from? Points like (-1800, -1800), etc.
And the vector vi contained only (1,1).

[This is the image of point 1 1 being sent in and the triangle has many points.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3qoK.png)

[image: This is the image of point 1 1 being sent in and the triangle has many points.]

```
cout << "Enter first images' tie points:\t";
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    Point2f p(a, b);
    vi.push_back(p);
}
```

The logic for generating triangles is below:

```
Size size = I.size();
Rect R(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
Subdiv2D a(R);
//a.initDelaunay(R);

for( vector<Point2f>::iterator it = vi.begin(); it != vi.end(); it++)
{
    a.insert(*it);
}

vector<Vec6f> triangle;
a.getTriangleList(triangle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but getTriangleList() also returns triangles that are outside the image. It probably has to do with how the Voronoi diagram is made, but I don't understand how these triangles could help us. So you need to remove those triangles. I did that function that worked for me. About 20% of the triangles but completly or partialy out of the image.

```
std::vector<Vec6f> FaceMorpher::pointsToTriangles(std::vector<Point2f> points)
{
  Rect rect(0, 0, _widthImage, _heightmage); //choose the space we want to work in, in this case all the image
  Subdiv2D subdiv(rect); //object representing the points is a Voronoi diagram so it can easily triangulise the points
  for (auto& point : points)
    subdiv.insert(point); //subdiv updates the Voronoi diagram each time a point is inserted

  std::vector<Vec6f> triangles;
  subdiv.getTriangleList(triangles); //generate the triangles by splitting polygons formed by Voronoi diagram into triangles

  //Remove triangles that are not  completly inside the image
  std::vector<Vec6f> trianglesInsideImg;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < triangles.size(); i++)
  {
    Vec6f t = triangles[i];
    auto p1 = Point(cvRound(t[0]), cvRound(t[1]));
    auto p2 = Point(cvRound(t[2]), cvRound(t[3]));
    auto p3 = Point(cvRound(t[4]), cvRound(t[5]));

    if (rect.contains(p1) && rect.contains(p2) && rect.contains(p3))
    {
      Vec6f triangle;
      triangle[0] = p1.x;
      triangle[1] = p1.y;
      triangle[2] = p2.x;
      triangle[3] = p2.y;
      triangle[4] = p3.x;
      triangle[5] = p3.y;
      trianglesInsideImg.push_back(triangle);
    }
  }

  return trianglesInsideImg; 
}
```